# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".54870736.54870896.54871216.54871728"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, runtime-error

My program is a timed addition quiz. It works just fine but this error message keeps appearing after I input an incorrect answer (command=submit_answer). This is the whole error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maggie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Maggie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 596, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Maggie\Documents\python\prototype2.py", line 115, in countdown
    self.label.configure(text="%d" % self.remaining)
  File "C:\Users\Maggie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1330, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Maggie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1321, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".54870736.54870896.54871216.54871728"
```

This is the code to my program:

```
class Add(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="blue")
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Main Menu", font=LARGE_FONT, background="white",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Main))
        button.place(relx=0.83, rely=0.92)

        self.button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Start Game", font=LARGE_FONT, background="white",
                           command=self.time_start)
        self.button4.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.8, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.2)

        self.after_id = None

    def time_start(self):
        self.button4.destroy()

        self.x = int(random.uniform(1,10))
        self.y = int(random.uniform(50,100))
        self.z = int(random.uniform(10,50))
        print(self.x+self.y+self.z)

        self.qlabel = tk.Label(self, text= (self.x,"+",self.y,"+",self.z,"=",), font=WORD_FONT, bg="blue")
        self.qlabel.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.3, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.3)

        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.2)

        self.ebutton = tk.Button(self, text="Done", font=TITLE_FONT, background="white",
                            command=self.submit_answer)
        self.ebutton.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.5, relheight=0.2, relwidth=0.3)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="", width=10, font=LARGE_FONT, bg="white")
        self.label.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
        self.remaining = 0
        self.countdown(10)

    def submit_answer(self):
        a = (self.x+self.y+self.z)
        if int(self.e1.get()) == a:
            answerlabel = tk.Label(self, text="Correct!", font=LARGE_FONT, background="blue")
            answerlabel.place(relx=0.42, rely=0.1, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.2)
            self.label.destroy()
            self.qlabel.destroy()
            self.e1.destroy()
            self.ebutton.destroy()
            self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
            self.time_start()
        else:
            answerlabel = tk.Label(self, text="Game Over.", font=LARGE_FONT, background="blue")
            answerlabel.place(relx=0.42, rely=0.1, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.2)
            self.ebutton.destroy()
            self.label.destroy()
            self.restartbutton = tk.Button(self, text="Reset Game", font=LARGE_FONT, background="white",
                                  command= self.reset_game)
            self.restartbutton.place(relx=0.65, rely=0.92)

    def countdown(self, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining
        if self.remaining <= 0:
            self.after_id = None
            self.label.configure(text="Time's up!")
            self.ebutton.destroy()           
        else:
            self.label.configure(text="%d" % self.remaining)
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.after_id = self.after(1000, self.countdown)

    def reset_game(self):
        self.button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Start Game", font=LARGE_FONT, background="white",
                           command=self.time_start)
        self.button4.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.8, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.2)
        self.label.destroy()
        self.qlabel.destroy()
        self.e1.destroy()
        self.ebutton.destroy()
        blanklabel = tk.Label(self, background="blue")
        blanklabel.place(relx=0.42, rely=0.1, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.2)
        self.restartbutton.destroy()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A job that was started with `after` is trying to modify a widget after that widget has been destroyed.